# Install multiple APK with adb

Tags: android, apk, adb

I try to install a apk on my android emulator device.

I tried some tricks. When I changed the extension to zip, I saw many apk and one json file in the zip (config.apk, config.arm64_v8a...) ...
So I tried to install apk one by one, the app is installed but the app crash... And I can't install some apk.

I tried :

- adb install file.apk
- adb install-multiple file1.apk file2.apk

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean? I use android studio to generate apk, not to install them, what do you want to achieve? Do you maybe expect to see the code if you install the apk?

Comment: I failed sorry, for android emulator. I want install a app on my emulator and watch the http traffic. But I can't install this app throught "adb install"

Comment: do not know do not have experience on that

Comment: `adb install-multiple base.apk config.apk` should work. Please share the error message and stacktrace if you find it in the adb logcat.

Comment: install_failed_no_matching_abis: failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

I have this error... I tried to change build.gradle same error...

Answer (score 0):

`adb install-multiple` should do the work:

```
adb install-multiple [-lrtsdpg] [--instant] <apk files>
  - push multiple APKs to the device for a single package and install them
       (-l: forward lock application)
       (-r: replace existing application)
       (-t: allow test packages)
       (-s: install application on sdcard)
       (-d: allow version code downgrade)
       (-p: partial application install)
       (-g: grant all runtime permissions)
```

For example:

```
adb install-multiple base.apk config.en.apk config.xxhdpi.apk
```